# recommended way for "reminder" on Android similar to iPhone's icon badge

Tags: android, widget

Since Android does not directly have icon badges I would like to use app widget as a reminder.

The idea behind this is that if a user wants to remind her/himself to do a certain task within my app the app widget should show it, otherwise either the app widget is not on the screen (if that is possible at all) or the widget just shows by its nature that everything is OK.

Ideally I would like to have an app, (not a widget) that just shows a widget as a reminder.

Is this the "recommended" way to do this or do I just need to make a widget that changes its look and forget about the app?

**Can I actually make an app widget appear and disappear from within an app?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I actually make an app widget appear and disappear from within an app?

If by "disappear" you mean "draw nothing but take up space", sure. Use a `RemoteViews` that has transparent contents, then update the app widget with that `RemoteViews`.

Personally, I don't like the UX of this, and I would suggest that perhaps you allow the user to choose between "invisible" or "default" app widget contents when there is no reminder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you please explain. Do you mean I would have an app + its visible/invisible app widget which is optional to the user - or are you just talking about the app widget without an app? So could I have an app where the user decides if she/he wants to see the app widget as a reminder and if not the space is always taken but empty?

Comment: @user387184: You have to have an app. App widgets do not exist on their own.

Comment: Sorry to ask one more time. Can I add the app widget from within the app (after having asked the user if it's ok) then or does the user have to add it like any normal app widget and then from within the app it's look will be changed?

Comment: @user387184: "Can I add the app widget from within the app" -- absolutely not.

Comment: So finally :-), user installs the app and decides if she/he wants to also have the app widget. If yes, I ask the user in the app if the widget should be shown or not in case there is no reminder? Is this the correct way then?

Comment: @user387184: The user will add the app widget to her home screen if she feels like it, using her home screen app. If she does, you will find out about that, and you can elect to update it as you see fit. Why you are going this route rather than using a `Notification` is beyond me.

Comment: "Why you are going this route rather than using a Notification is beyond me.", simply because it is just more visible than a notification among the long list of other notifications. Basically it's a reminder to push a button in the app to confirm sending a SMS, which we do not want to be sent without explicit user confirmation. On iPhone we can just use the badge number

Comment: @user387184: "simply because it is just more visible than a notification among the long list of other notifications" -- this is *only* true if the user is looking at *the portion of the home screen where the app widget is installed*. The rest of the time, the user will have no idea that your app widget is doing anything. I hope that you will also add support in your app for accessibility events, since you will not be getting such events automatically from a `Notification`.

Comment: The app is beeing used on a daily basis as a utility to control certain houshold devices per SMS, like starting to cook coffee. This would be the reminder to remotely programm the coffee machine for the next morning - or for more "dangerous" equipment which needs an explicit user confirmation instead of an automated repetition like turning on the oven